# How to define a relative path for Swagger in v5?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am upgrading my .NET Core app from Swashbuckle v4 to v5.  I currently have the following code in Startup.ConfigureServices that defines the relative path:

```
app.UseSwagger(c => {
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = "/folder/data");
});
```

I am having trouble converting this to v5.  I tried the following, but I don't see where to set the path:

```
c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
{
    var paths = new OpenApiPaths();
    var pathItem = new OpenApiPathItem();

    paths.Add("main", pathItem);
    swagger.Paths = paths;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In v5 basePath is replaced by Servers according to:** https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1173

You can set the path of the json file with routeTemplate and path for requests made from ui using servers:

```
var basePath = "/v1";
 app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
         c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
         c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
    {
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer 
                 { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{basePath}" } };
        });
    });
```

And to configure the ui:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi(options => 
     {
         options.swaggerEndpoint($"swagger/{apiVersion}/swagger.json, "my api v1");
     }
```

Relative paths can be used for the endpoint using ./ or ../

Comment: I am struggling with same issue as the question. This Answer does not solve it as I have the API in a Service Fabric cluster and so the IPon the cluster node gets added instead of the correct IP if I use this answer. All I want to do is set the basePath property, NOT the whole URL with host.  swagger.json should only hold: "basePath": "/folder/data" and not include a host propety with value, as this answer will produce.

Comment: Well, the answer i provided was not intended for your specific specialcase, but for the general case and OPs question...I kind of feel like the downvote is unwarranted just because it didnt help you. Ask a question specific to your situation, and you might get some good answers

Comment: ok. I haved asked the specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733433/how-do-i-setup-swashbucle-v5-with-swagger-when-i-have-a-custom-base-url