# How do I setup Swashbuckle v5 with swagger when I have a custom base url?

Tags: swagger, .net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am upgrading a .net API to .net Core 3.1 and using Swashbuckle.AspNetcore 5.4.1. The API is running inside a ServiceFabric app. I found this https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1173 and tried to follow that and swagger gets generated but if I try to use the Swagger UI to send requests the request URL is with the wrong IP so the request fail.
In the old Swashbuckle 4.0.1 setup we did not specify host, only the relative basePath. How can I achieve the same?

Startup.cs

```
var swaggerBasePath = "/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/";

app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SerializeAsV2 = serializeAsSwaggerV2;
    
    c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
    {
        swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{swaggerBasePath}" } };
    });
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("api/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

The result is that the Swagger UI loads correctly on URL:

```
http://145.12.23.1:54000/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/swagger/index.html
```

and it says under name that BaseUrl is:

```
[ Base URL: 10.0.0.4:10680/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/ ]
```

The 10.0.0.4:10680 is the node inside the ServiceFabric cluster. Correct IP to reach from outside is 145.12.23.1:54000. In the older version (4.0.1) of Swashbuckle it says baseUrl without IP first: "/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi"

Swagger.json is located at:

```
http://40.68.213.118:19081/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/swagger/api/swagger.json
```

and it says:

```
"swagger": "2.0",
... 
"host": "10.0.0.4:10680",  
"basePath": "/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/",
"schemes": [
"http"
],
"paths": {
"/activity/{activityId}": {
"get"
...etc
```

If i try to send a GET request from the Swagger UI the request is sent to wrong IP:

```
curl -X GET "http://10.0.0.4:10680/MySfApp/MySfApp/activity/3443"
```

---

EDIT 1:
After some digging I have now changed the setup to this in
startup.cs

```
var swaggerBasePath = "/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/";
app.UsePathBase($"/{swaggerBasePath}");
app.UseMvc();
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SerializeAsV2 = serializeAsSwaggerV2;

    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
    {
        if (!httpReq.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Original-Host")) 
            return;

        var serverUrl = $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Proto"]}://" +
                        $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Host"]}/" +
                        $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Prefix"]}";

        swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>()
        {
            new OpenApiServer { Url = serverUrl }
        };
    });
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("api/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

This now leads to the Swagger UI loading properly with the baseUrl

```
http://145.12.23.1:54000/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/swagger/index.html
```

and also swagger.json is served correctly with the correct baseUrl.

```
http://145.12.23.1:54000/MySfApp/SfApp.ClientApi/swagger/api/swagger.json
```

So the wrong hostname is resolved. [Thanks to idea from this thread](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1298#issuecomment-620269062).

However when I try to call an endpoint from the Swagger UI page, the curl URL does not include the baseUrl. So closer... but currently not possible to use Swagger UI.

```
curl -X GET "http://10.0.0.4:10680/activity/3443"
```

The swagger.json does not have 'host' nor 'basePath' defined.

Answer (score 4):

We're using Swashbuckle version `6.1.4` - which is the latest as of this time of writing and we're still having the same issue when our API is deployed in Azure App Service that is mapped through Azure Front Door and APIM. The "Try out" functionality does not work as the base path / api route prefix is stripped from the Swagger UI. For example,

Instead of `https://{DOMAIN}.com/{BASEPATH}/v1/Foo`, the Swagger UI uses this: `https://{DOMAIN}.com/v1/Foo`. You can see that the `/BASEPATH` is missing.

I spent the whole day trying to fix this with trial and error, trying various approaches with no luck, I couldn't get an elegant way to get the base path from swagger configuration. For the time being, here's what I did to fix it:

```cs
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    //Workaround to use the Swagger UI "Try Out" functionality when deployed behind a reverse proxy (APIM) with API prefix /sub context configured
    options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
    {
         if (httpReq.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Host"))
         {
            //The httpReq.PathBase and httpReq.Headers["X-Forwarded-Prefix"] is what we need to get the base path.
            //For some reason, they returning as null/blank. Perhaps this has something to do with how the proxy is configured which we don't have control.
            //For the time being, the base path is manually set here that corresponds to the APIM API Url Prefix.
            //In this case we set it to 'sample-app'. 
    
            var basePath = "sample-app"
            var serverUrl = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"]}/{basePath}";
            swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = serverUrl } };
         }
    });
})
.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Api (v1)");
});
```

Here's an open discussion related to this issue [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2004).

Comment: Almost a solution except the hardcoded `basePath`... there would have to be another header to let the app know what's the base path in case of a need to make it easy portable without re-deploying, but I belive it's a swagger UI problem, because from there it should be able to detect the base URL that is not always to be a root domain

Answer (score 1):

I were having something similar in my solution and I have used a little bit this way and that works well for me, in case that helps someone.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   var pathBase = Configuration["PATH_BASE"];
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathBase))
   { 
      app.UsePathBase($"/{pathBase.TrimStart('/')}");
      app.Use((context, next) =>
      {
          context.Request.PathBase = new PathString($"/{pathBase.TrimStart('/')}");
          return next();
      });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseSwagger(c =>
       {
           c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
           {
                 if (!httpReq.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Original-Host"))
                 return;

                 var serverUrl = $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Proto"]}://" + $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Host"]}/" + $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Original-Prefix"]}";

                 swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>()
                 {
                     new OpenApiServer { Url = serverUrl }
                 }
           });
       });
       app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{pathBase.TrimStart('/')}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My.API v1"));    
    }
   }
}
```

check the last line
**app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{pathBase.TrimStart('/')}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My.API v1"));**

Comment: Today, I did little more digging and I found an answer. you don't have to provide base URL or path base for swagger.json and may be because there could be a reverse proxy on top of your code. so, better way to do that is
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My.API v1"));

this is also recommended at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1253

Comment: Thanks. Link helped to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    `serverUrl = $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"]}://" +
                $"{httpReq.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"]}" + _basePath;`
where _basePath can be set using the ServiceName property of StatelessServiceContext.
Please be noted that the original value of X-Forwarded-Proto may be overridden by SF.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the _basePath value? Do you mean getting it from the configuration?
Do you have an example for this. This code is run in startup.cs `public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version based on [Vincent Maverick Durano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67696746/1818723) answer.
The idea is to be portable without hardcoding the paths. I take the Referer header sent by a browser and use that url as base. This is with the assumption your app is configured to have index.html in the root of the API.

When you host the app directly it would be something like `https://example.com/index.html` and the UI API call to be something like `https://example.com/v1/users`.

When you host the app via proxy like Azure Front Door using routing you would want something like `https://anotherexample.com/myapp/index.html` the whole `https://example.com/` is proxied as `https://anotherexample.com/myapp/` thus index that follows with that, so the UI API call to be `https://anotherexample.com/myapp/v1/users`

The code

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    //Workaround to use the Swagger UI "Try Out" functionality when deployed behind a reverse proxy with routing
    options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
    {
        //The assumption is being made here that index.html is hosted in the root of a virtual directory where a route can be a root
        //example without a proxy
        //https://example.com/index.html <-- the API is directly accesible at domain root like domain.com/v1/users
        //
        //example with a proxy and routing
        //https://example.com/appx/index.html <-- the API is accesible at domain.com/appx "root" like domain.com/appx/v1/users
        //everything should be relative to domain.com/appx
        if (httpReq.Headers.ContainsKey("Referer"))
        {
            var referer = httpReq.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
            var index = referer.IndexOf("index.html");
            var basePath = referer.Remove(index);
            swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = basePath } };
        }
    });
});
```

And swagger UI registration with relative path and versioning

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version, and show latest as first
    for (var i = versionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var description = versionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions[i];
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

If you don't support versioning then only important line is `c.SwaggerEndpoint($"swagger/` notice `$"swagger` starts without `/` to make the UI relative to the proxy routing