# To get baseurl inside startup.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Is it possible to get baseurl inside the `app.UseSwaggerUI({})` in `configure()` method of `startup` class

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
     string baseurl = ?
     c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{baseurl}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"API {Version}");
});
```

In above code, I need to get the value in the variable `baseurl` as `"https://localhost:44335"` or `https://ap-qa.com/`

Comment: If you just make it a relative URL, it should just do the "right thing" based on the hostname of HTTP requests made to the application.

Comment: Can I get value of `httpReq.Host.Value` inside the above code?

Comment: Why do you want to set the Base url yourself? Is it different from the default inferred host name? Like said, if you use a relative url, it will be set to the request base hostname [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to get the base URL in ASP.NET Core at startup. That is because ASP.NET Core often runs behind a reverse proxy and therefore does not need to know which domains it is hosting.

You can get the base URL for a specific request later by looking at `HttpContext` but that won't help you at startup.

If using an absolute URL path like `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` is not suitable for your application, you can still add base URL to your app configuration in `appsettings.json`, environment variables or your preferred config provider.

Comment: A number of these statements are not true,  or at least these statements that only apply in a very specific situation. A lot is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use something like below?

```
string hostUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_URLS");
Console.WriteLine($"hostURL: {hostUrl}");
```

NOTE: If there are multiple (for developer with http and https together), you know which one you like to take.

I also posted soething related at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733433/how-do-i-setup-swashbuckle-v5-with-swagger-when-i-have-a-custom-base-url/70343309#70343309) which together will help you.

Comment: Today, I did little more digging and I found an answer. you don't have to provide base URL or path base for swagger.json and may be because there could be a reverse proxy on top of your code. so, better way to do that is
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My.API v1"));

this is also recommended at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1253